# problem while generating xsd

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I have a xsd file with the following xml structure. No matter what i do the MyVals enumerator is not getting generated.

```
<xs:simpleType name="MyVals">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="1" />
       <xs:enumeration value="2" />
       <xs:enumeration value="3" />
       <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
     </xs:restriction>   
</xs:simpleType>
```

All other structures are correctly populating. Complete xsd is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.simple.com/xsd" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="1.0"
    xmlns:wepa="http://www.simple.com/xsd"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    >

  <xs:element name="MessageProtocol" >
    <xs:complexType >
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name ="Header" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name ="Body" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>




  <xs:simpleType name="MyVals">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="1" />
      <xs:enumeration value="2" />
      <xs:enumeration value="3" />
      <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

XSD generation command:C:\Progra~1\"Microsoft SDKs"\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe -c /enabledDataBinding -l:c# /namespace:Simple.SimpleXSD Simple.xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MyVals type is not used within your MessageProtocol element

For starters, try declaring the Body element as follows:

```
<xs:element name="Body" type="MyVals" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using that type anywhere, so it wont be used.